# how to solve the error "THREE.GLTFLoader: Failed to load buffer "scene.bin"."?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a tutorial in youtube and doing as per it but i stumbled at the beginning itself can anyone help

[image]

```
let scene, camera, renderer;
    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, Window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
        camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
        camera.position.x = 800;
        camera.position.y = 100;
        camera.position.z = 1000;
        hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 100);
        scene.add(hlight);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('scene.gltf', function (gltf) {
            car = gltf.scene.children[0];
            car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            scene.add(gltf.scene);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        });
    }
    init();
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem a few days ago, and here's what the problem turned out to be:

I had my scene.gltf file and my scene.bin files in different subfolders, but when you supply the path to your gltf object, the GLTFLoader expects the scene.bin file to be in the same directory.

> Fixing this should be easy: just put both files in the same directory,
>   and everything will proceed swimmingly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check if or how the GLTFLoader.js file is loaded. See [this](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) - there is a link at the end of the page to [GLTFLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js) or you can add as `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r92/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and the reason was `http-server` which i installed from node package manager `npm install http-server`. I then switched to `wamp` which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Further adding to Davide's post, make sure gltf, bin, and textures are all in the same folder. For some reason loading the model only worked when I placed all of these files in the public directory

Answer (score 0):

When the bin file is not loaded correctly on your computer, there might be some issues with your web server.I think your web server blocked the loading of the. bin file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).